# android imported spring jar occurs NoClassDefFoundError error?

Tags: android, spring, noclassdeffounderror

I had imported `spring-2.5.6.jar` and `spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar` by

> `Build Path`->`Configure Build Path`->`Add Library`->`User library`->`New`->...->`Add Jars`

`NoClassDefFoundError` occurs. Java code:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(   
            "invoker-client.xml");
```

Error message:

> `11-16 07:11:57.685: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1555): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`

I had tried to create a new folder "libs" in the project, and `Build Path -> Use as Source Folder`, but it can't compile, or by putting jar files under "assets" folder:
`Project -> Clean -> ...`

But none of these work. Could anyone suggest me a solution, please?

Comment: Try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941][1]. I explained different approaches for importing JAR files into Android studio. I hope it helps.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35343238/5475941